# Select field using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

There is the following generated HTML code:

```
    <label for="place_type_id">Type</label><br />
    <select id="place_type_id" name="place[type_id]"><option value="1">Restaurant</option>
<option value="2">Cafe</option>
<option value="3">Club</option></select>
```

I need to select some option for my RSpec test:

```
  select "Club", from: "place[type_id]"
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix it? I've tried to use 'id' instead of 'name' in 'from' parameter, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you clarify what "it doesn't work" means? Is there an exception (if so, please give the stack trace)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the select box can be found by name, id or label text so your example looks like it should work. From [Capybara::Node::Actions](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method):

> Find a select box on the page and select a particular option from it.
>   If the select box is a multiple select, select can be called multiple
>   times to select more than one option. The select box can be found via
>   its name, id or label text.

We're obviously overlooking something though. Maybe the square brackets is throwing off capybara? See what happens when selecting by the label text.

```
select 'Club', from: 'Type'
```

Or id:

```
select 'Club', from: :place_type_id
```